# unable to call wcf method from rest client with base64 string

Tags: wcf, rest-client

i am creating a wcf service in which i am  receiving a base64 string and converting to image to store in my project.

this is my method:

```
 public Boolean UploadProfile(int UserId, string base64String, string FileExtension)
        {
            try
            {
                string fileExtension;
                byte[] bytes = Convert.FromBase64String(base64String);
                if (FileExtension == "")
                    fileExtension = ".png";
                else
                    fileExtension = FileExtension;

                String timeStamp = GetTimestamp(DateTime.Now);
                fileExtension = timeStamp + fileExtension;
                string strFileName = "~/Images/" + fileExtension;
                using (UserRegistrationBal UserregistrationBal = new UserRegistrationBal())
                {
                    using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(bytes))
                    {
                        Image image = Image.FromStream(stream);
                        image.Save(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(strFileName));
                        UserregistrationBal.UploadProfile(UserId, fileExtension);
                    }
                    return true;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                ErrorLogManager.LogError(ex);
                return false;
            }
        }




public static String GetTimestamp(DateTime value)
        {
            return value.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmssffff");
        }
```

My interface:

```
 [ServiceContract]
    public interface Services 
    {
           [OperationContract]
        [WebInvoke(RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedRequest, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, Method = "POST")]
        Boolean UploadProfile(int UserId, string base64String, string FileExtension);
}
```

now when i am calling this method from my rest client like this:

[image]

then my method is not calling from rest client.

i have kept debugger on my method but my nothing happens

when i am passing blank base64 parameter then my method is calling.

can anybody tell me whats the problem??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have a issue with file size, please change maxBufferSize, maxBufferPoolSize and                  maxReceivedMessageSize to

```
         maxBufferSize="2147483647"
         maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647"
         maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647"
```

from your binding then try,
i think it should work.
and try to add

```
 <readerQuotas  maxDepth="2147483647"
 maxStringContentLength="2147483647"
 maxArrayLength="2147483647"
 maxBytesPerRead="2147483647"
 maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647"/>
```

in your binding. 
it will upload large file to REST Service.

Comment: but problem is not that

Comment: but still can u please post ur whole part of web.config.i mean not whole web.config but only that part of web.config whcih contain readerquotas part

Comment: <webHttpBinding>
        <binding name="MyWcfRestService" maxBufferSize="2147483647"
                 maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647"
                 maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647"
                 transferMode="Streamed"
                 sendTimeout="00:05:00">
          <readerQuotas  maxDepth="2147483647"
                         maxStringContentLength="2147483647"
                         maxArrayLength="2147483647"
                         maxBytesPerRead="2147483647"
                         maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647"/>
               </binding>
      </webHttpBinding>

Comment: thank u so much pal for helping me.thank you once again and keep helping